# How i can to create new model inside another model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have TweetModel and i need to create RatingModel inside, and RatingModel must have a same TweetModel id, because i want to link them for further deletion.
Maybe there are other ways to make rating for posts in mongoose.
I will be very grateful for your help

```
const tweet = await TweetModel.create({
      text: req.body.text,
      images: req.body.images,
      user: user._id,
      rating: ..., // => {retweets[], likes[]}
    })
    tweet.save()
```

[TweetSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od7RA.png)

[RatingSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjMLs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to create Schema, you can create 2 different schemas for your tweet and rating. This will create 2 separate collections will inturn be more manageable.

```
const { text, images } = req.body

const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() //create a objectId first.

await TweetModel.updateOne({ _id }, { text, images, user: user._id }, { upsert: true })
await RatingModel.updateOne(....)
```

We are using updateOne here with the option of `{upsert: true}` where we will create a new record if record `_id` don't exist.

You will be able to get the ratings easily with [mongoose.populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

More on `{ upsert: true }` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

#### Bonus

If you want to create the record in half the time.

```
const [ tweet, rating ] = await Promise.all([
      TweetModel.updateOne({ _id }, { text, images, user: user._id }, { upsert: true })
      RatingModel.updateOne(....)
])
```

Using Promise.all you can execute both update request at the same time.

#### Bonus 2

If you want to populate ratings inside tweet, add this in your Schema..

```
TweetModel.virtual('rating', {
  ref: 'Rating',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: '_id',
});
```

Scroll to Populate - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html